# Connectedness in proximity spaces

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $\delta$ be a [proximity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_space).

A set $A$ is connected regarding $\delta$ iff $\forall X,Y \in \mathscr{P} A \setminus \{ \emptyset \} : \left( X \cup Y = A
\Rightarrow X \mathrel{\delta} Y \right)$.

**Conjecture** The following statements are equivalent for every endofuncoid $\mu$ and a set $U$:

- $U$ is connected regarding $\mu$.
- For every $a, b \in U$ there exists a totally ordered set $P \subseteq
    U$ such that $\min P = a$, $\max P = b$, and for every partion $\{ X, Y \}$
  of $P$ into two sets $X$, $Y$ such that $\forall x \in X, y \in Y : x < y$,
  we have $X \mathrel{[ \mu]^{\ast}} Y$.

Comment: I've edited the question. Now it is a somehow different conjecture